# Hibernate delete and update

Tags: java, hibernate, oracle11g, hibernate-mapping

I have a java object set to update. I used SaveOrUpdate method to do that.it works fine for updating children, but there is an issue with my requirement.

because I need to delete a child from database if one child is deleted.

please anyone have an good idea to implement this ?

Ex :-

project has a one to many relationship with people.

project has a atribute like,

```
  class Project { 
    long id;
    Set<People> people;
    ......
 }

public void updateProject(Project project) {

    try {
        getCurrentSession().saveOrUpdate(project);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        logger.error(ex);
    }
```

project object contains people set but deleted some people Ids from that.

I need to update project with deleting unwanted people Ids

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I assume you have enabled cascading on your Project entity so my guess is that you need to add the orphanRemoval attribute to the relation.
Example for your case would be:

```
@OneToMany(cascade={CascadeType.ALL}, orphanRemoval=true)
```

Comment: Thank you for your anwser. I have a small question. if when Im going to update the child, someone can add new child with assigning to the project. in that case,if we are going to use this, what will be happened ? deleted newly added one also ?

Comment: I'm not quite sure that I understand your question completely but, 
as long as you add new children to the set in the people set and you do the saveOrUpdate of the project everything should be fine. The new child will be saved because of the cascading

Answer (score 0):

**Ref Code:**    Configure cascade with 'all-delete-orphan' for removing orphan data...

```
<hibernate-mapping>
      <class name="User" table="UTABLE" >
          <id name="UID" column="UID"/>
          <property name="Name"  column="F_Name"/>
          <set name="phones"   table="PHONE_NUMBERS" cascade="all-delete-orphan" lazy="true">
          <key column="UID"/>
            <one-to-many class="PhoneNumber"  />
         </set>
      </class>
  </hibernate-mapping>
```